# Unable to render views in my Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm unable to see the results of my views in my Rails app.

I just installed Ruby on a Ubuntu 10.4 Lucid Server.

here's my controller/method:

```
def testing
     @text = 'This is some text'
end
```

The controller's name is `new`

The View:

```
<h1><%= @text %></h1>
```

I get a 500 Internal Server error when i try to load up:

```
 `http://servername/new/testing`
```

in my browser...

EDIT:
i'm missing `application.rhtml` file in the `layouts` folder do you think that might be the problem?

Comment: its called `testing.html.erb` I've tried .rhtml as the extension as well... doesnt work..

Comment: i'm missing `application.rhtml` file in the `layouts` folder do you think that might be the problem?

Comment: rails relies on convention over configuration.. make sure the layout is right ..also get the stack trace

Comment: What Rails version are you using? It should be layouts/application.html.erb not .rhtml

Comment: @doon the production.log shows an internal server error 500

Comment: @Patrick, I'll try that and post the result here. Why would my application layout be missing altogether?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are running in production (I am assuming this since you said production.log)? I would suggest running the app in development as they logs are much more explicit about what is going wrong when you have an error.

Comment: Hello sosburn, how would i check if my Rails app is deployed in production mode or not?

Comment: @patrick, the file is aptly called `layouts/application.html.erb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'new' might be a reserved word which prevents from rendering, but I'm not sure about that. Did you set up the route for the controller?

```
resources :new do
  member do
    get 'testing'
  end
end
```

You can generate controllers, actions, views and routes by using

```
rails g controller new testing
```

Comment: That's the routes for Rails 3. For 2.x it would be something like map.connect 'testing', :controller => 'new', :action => 'testing'.